# How to match multiple conditions on JOIN query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to retrieve all the users that match a multiple join conditions.

Here is a simplify example with this database :

```
create table users(id int, name varchar);
insert into users values(1, "caroline"); 
insert into users values(2, "simon");
insert into users values(3, "jose");
insert into users values(4, "robert");
create table tags(value varchar, user_id integer);

insert into tags values("a", 1); insert into tags values("b", 1);
insert into tags values("a", 2);insert into tags values("b", 3);
insert into tags values("c", 4);
```

I want to get the user that have the tag 'a' and the tag 'b' (caroline).

If I run this query :
`SELECT * from users INNER JOIN tags ON users.id = tags.user_id WHERE tags.value IN ('a', 'b');`

It return all the users that match one of the two conditions :

```
1|caroline|a|1
1|caroline|b|1
2|simon|a|2
3|jose|b|3
```

If I run this query :

```
SELECT * FROM users where users.id IN (
SELECT users.id from users INNER JOIN tags ON users.id = tags.user_id WHERE tags.value = 'a'
INTERSECT
SELECT users.id from users INNER JOIN tags ON users.id = tags.user_id WHERE tags.value = 'b');
```

It works. Only caroline is return.

But it's 3 selects queries in this case. But is real usage, if I have 5 tags to search, it will be 6 select queries.

Is there a better solutions that create subqueries?

Comment: I use sqlite. I just add it. And I create this dummy test with https://sqliteonline.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select u.id, u.name
from users u
inner join tags t on u.id = t.user_id 
where t.value in ('a', 'b')
group by u.id, u.name
having count(distinct t.value) = 2
```

The query groups all `tags` records of the same user, filters on a list of tag values, and ensure that they are all present.

If you had 6 tags to check for, you would do:

```
select u.id, u.name
from users u
inner join tags t on u.id = t.user_id 
where t.value in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
group by u.id, u.name
having count(distinct t.value) = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach uses aggregation to find users having both of the desired tags.  Then, join to the `users` table to bring in the actual username.

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id
    FROM tags
    WHERE value IN ('a', 'b')
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING MIN(value) <> MAX(value)
) t
    ON u.id = t.user_id;
```

Another option, using self join:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN tags t1
    ON u.id = t1.user_id
INNER JOIN tags t2
    ON u.id = t2.user_id
WHERE
    t1.value = 'a' AND
    t2.value = 'b';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions. 
One could be to use joins on tags table for each tag you need to check :

```
SELECT u.id, u.name FROM users u
INNER JOIN tags t1 ON (u.id = t1.user_id AND t1.value = 'a')
INNER JOIN tags t2 ON (u.id = t2.user_id AND t2.value = 'b');
```

Another could be to use group_concat :

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.value ORDER BY t.value)
FROM users u
JOIN tags t on u.id = t.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(t.value) = 'a,b'
```

To be sure to get users that match others tags than a and b, you could change the having clause with:

```
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(t.value) LIKE '%a%b%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also join against the same table multiple times

```
SELECT users.name FROM users 
INNER JOIN tags t1 ON users.id = t1.user_id AND t1.value = 'a'
INNER JOIN tags t2 ON users.id = t1.user_id AND t1.value = 'b'
WHERE t1.user_id=t2.user_id
AND users.id=t1.user_id
```

Not sure which of the answers will be more performant?

Answer (score 0):

You can change `cn > 1` according to your requirement. (ex: if 5 tags to be searched then `cn > 4` )

```
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT name, count(*) cn FROM users 
      INNER JOIN tags ON 
      users.id = tags.user_id 
      WHERE tags.value IN ('a', 'b')
      group by name
    ) WHERE cn > 1;
```